# Grouping and null values in column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Need some help in how to fix a problem.

Below is my input data. Here I am doing a group by based on name field. The query which I am currently used for grouping is given below.

[image]

```
select name from Table
group by name having count(distinct DOB)='1'
```

But the problem is that the above query won't fecth records if the DOB field is null for all records within a group.In case if I try to give some dummy value for DOB field, then It won't fetch the result for first two rows and if I didn't give the dummy value for it won't fecth the records in 3 and 4

I tried something like this, but it is wrong

```
select name from Table
group by name having count(distinct case when DOB is null then '9999-01-01' else DOB END)='1'
```

Could someone help here with some suggestions. My expected result is given below.

[image]

Comment: Start thinking about your code. Count returns an integer. So why do you compare it to a string literal? This is a lazy and bad habit - relying on implicit conversion to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the logic with:

```
having min(dob) = max(dob) or
       min(dob) is null
```

Depending on your data, `count(distinct)` can be relatively expensive, so this can actually be cheaper than using it.

You *can* use `count(distinct)`.  Just change the comparison value:

```
having count(distinct dob) <= 1
```

Comment: Yea this is a good one and it worked. I just change the condition